# Remove bidirectional relations in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

How to remove bidirectional relation between two nodes of same label and make it single relation between those two nodes irrespective of the direction.

For example:

```
(a:Label1)-[r]->(b:Label1) && (b:Label1)-[r]->(a:Label1)
```

What I need is either of `a-[r]->b` or `b-[r]->a`

If I use this:

```
 MATCH (a:Label1)-[r]->(b:Label1)
```

It is removing all relations.

Is it because of same label?

Answer (score 0):

Use `collect` and `tail` function:

```
MATCH (a:Label1)-[r]-(b:Label1)
WITH a, b, collect(r) as rels
UNWIND tail(rels) as rel
DELETE rel
```

Comment: tail gives first elements of collection, what if I have some extra single relation between some x and y

Comment: @chikku In this case, you need to give us a more formal definition of `bidirectional relationship`. PS `tail` remove first element of collection.